# How to manage cursors and sorting in Relay?

Tags: relayjs

We have a graphql server (not written in javascript) serving a paginated list of objects. We're trying to conform to the relay specification, but we've hit an interesting case that could use clarification.

Specifically: are cursors allowed to depend on other inputs to the connection? Similar to https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/issues/20, our connection takes a sort_key argument that determines the sort order of the returned list. Depending on the specified sort order, the edge for an object may return different cursor values (since the server needs different information in each case to determine the next object). However, a careful reading of https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html#range-add suggests this is not permitted; mutations that return a newly created edge must return a single cursor that can be universally applied to all possible lists in which that edge may appear? How does facebook solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. So, I decided to write a `npm` package to handle this issue.

You can use [fast-relay-pagination](https://github.com/saeedghx68/fast-relay-pagination) npm package for sorting, backward and forward `pagination` and filter `Mongoose` model or `MongoDB` object.

This package improves `graphql-relay` **lazy loading** by using `Mongoose` or `MongoDB` find and limit. As you definitely know, `graphql-relay's` `connectionFromArray` fetchs all data and performs slicing on data, which is not efficient for large amount.

---

You can see an example in below:

```
...
import {
  fetchConnectionFromArray
} from 'fast-relay-pagination'
...
export default{
  type: orderConnection.connectionType,
  args: {
    ...connectionArgs,
    orderFieldName: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    sortType: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
  },
  resolve: needAdmin(async (_, args) => {
    let orderFieldName = args.orderFieldName || '_id'
    let sortType = args.sortType || -1
    let after = args.after
    let before = args.before
    let filter = args.filter
    let first = args.first
    let last = args.last
    return fetchConnectionFromArray({
      dataPromiseFunc: SampleModel.find.bind(SampleModel), // required
      filter, // optional (for using filter on model collection) - for example => {username: 'test'} 
      after, //optiona
      before, // optional
      first, //optional
      last, // optional
      orderFieldName, // optional
      sortType, // optional
    })
  }),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the cursor should contain enough information in it to enable fetching the next page from that point onwards (including constraints such as sorting and filtering), but whether/how you do this is up to you as it is implementation-specific.

As for mutations, in your `getConfigs()` implementation you can specify `rangeBehaviors` on a per-call basis. So, if you have a sorted view, you might choose to append or prepend depending on the sort order. This behavior specifies what Relay will do on the client-side to update its store. It's still your responsibility to ensure that the code your GraphQL server receives all the information it needs (via input variables) to correctly perform the actual mutation.

Comment: I don't think I explained my concern properly, here's a more concrete example: you have two views on the same relay-paginated list, sorted by different fields. The same object appears on both lists, but with different cursors. You have a mutation to create an object, with a `RANGE_ADD` that specifies different behaviours for the two views. The mutation on the server side has to return a single cursor in the response; which of the two cursors does it return, and what does the other view do since it doesn't have a cursor at all?

Comment: Good point. It's possible that we haven't run into this internally because we haven't yet built mutations on connections which take this kind of parameter. Let's re-open [your original GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/760) again and see if we can work out a solution.

Comment: You can prepend and append but what about put the item on the 3rd position top to bottom for example? For example you had a thing sorted by name with [A,B,D] and you add C ?