# GraphQL + Relay Connection Optimization

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

Using Relay + GraphQL (graphql-relay-js) connections and trying to determine the best way to optimize queries to the data source etc.

Everything is working, though inefficient when connection results are sliced.  In the below query example, the resolver on item will obtain 200+ records for sale 727506341339, when in reality we only need 1 to be returned.

I should note that in order to fulfill this request we actually make two db queries: 
1. Obtain all items ids associated with a sale
2. Obtain item data for each item id.

In testing and reviewing of the graphql-relay-js src, it looks like the slice happens on the final connection resolver.

Is there a method provided, short of nesting connections or mutating the sliced results of connectionFromArray, that would allow us to slice the results provided to the connection (item ids) and then in the connection resolver fetch the item details against the already sliced id result set?  This would optimize the second query so we would only need to query for 1 items details, not all items...

Obviously we can implement something custom or nest connections, though it seems this is something that would be avail, thus I feel like I am missing something here...

Example Query:

```
query ItemBySaleQuery {
    viewer {
      item (sale: 727506341339) {
        items (first:1){
          edges {
            node {
              dateDisplay,
              title
            }
          }             
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You may solve your problem by my answer in following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948216/how-to-manage-cursors-and-sorting-in-relay/47865016#47865016

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the solution is not documented in the graphql-relay-js lib...

Connections can use resolveNode functions to work directly on an edge node.  Example: [https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/997e06993ed04bfc38ef4809a645d12c27c321b8/src/connection/**tests**/connection.js#L64](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/997e06993ed04bfc38ef4809a645d12c27c321b8/src/connection/__tests__/connection.js#L64)